# Will an undead companion naturally recover Hit Points?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, healing, hit-points

Here is the background. So, I am playing in a campaign where I have a homebrew spell with allows me a Zombie-like companion (basically a Zombie with additional HPs).

If I cast the spell every 8 hours for 8 days, I get to keep it as a permanent companion. However, I'm trying to work out how I can restore or increase its HPs, so that it doesn't die (lol) on me.

**Would a Zombie companion (un)naturally recover HPs each day?**

This is not a question about "healing" an undead creature such as a zombie.

Comment: Ok, so this is not a question about whether a Zombie can be healed at all, but specifically whether a Zombie companion would recover HP inherently somehow? (It sounds like 5e companions normally do that, is that right?)

Comment: The duplicate link I just added seems like the correct duplicate now, do you agree?

Comment: @doppelgreener Yes, that is what I was asking. The answer is in both of those links. Thanks NautArch as well.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've reopened the question so it can get its own independent & directed answer. Feel free to answer it yourself as well, if you'd like!

Comment: How does the Zombie appear? Is it a fey spirit that resembles a zombie, or an actual dead person who you "wake up" every time you cast the spell above their place of burial? Also, do you use the official Zombie stats or custom-made ones? It would be very helpful if you could also update the question with the homebrew spell description along with any limitations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Yes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Resting)

> Adventurers, **as well as other creatures**, can take short rests in the midst of a day and a long rest to end it.

Your [zombie](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/zombie) is an “other creature” and has no specific rule that says they can’t rest and benefit from doing so.